# refinerycms 'admin' tried to access 'refinery/admin/accommodations' but was rejected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms, refinery

In my refinery extension I have a Congress model that is the "main" model of the extension. Also, I have a Accommodation model that is nested in the Congress route like this:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :congresses do
    resources :accommodations
    as_routes       
  end
end
```

When I try to create a new Accommodation by its new action I get:

```
Processing by Refinery::Admin::AccommodationsController#new as HTML 
'admin' tried to access 'refinery/admin/accommodations' but was rejected.
 Filter chain halted as :restrict_controller rendered or redirected
```

Anybody have an idea of what is happening? The Accommodation new action is called on the Congress views, is this relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've found the solution to my problem in [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/refinery-cms/T5QfjWrtf6k).
Basically in these situations you have to add a line like this:

```
plugin.menu_match = /(admin|refinery)\/(congresses|accommodations)$/
```

to your "parent" model engine file, so that you can access the nested model controller.

At least it worked for me.